# Find 2nd highest country in terms of quantity purchased

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The question required me to find 2nd highest country in terms of quantity purchased. The quantity purchased and country are in different tables join via a third table but the code in retuning top 2 country I need only 2nd highest country.

```sql
SELECT c.country 
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid=o.customerid 
JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.orderid=od.orderid 
order by od.quantity desc 
limit 2
```

Comment: SELECT c.country FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid=o.customerid
              JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.orderid=od.orderid
                 order by od.quantity desc limit 2

Comment: is this mysql or sql server, you have tagged two RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OFFSET` see example

```
SELECT c.country 
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid=o.customerid 
JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.orderid=od.orderid 
ORDER BY od.quantity desc 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1

CREATE TABLE a (id int)


INSERT INTO a VALUES (1), (2),(3)
```

```
✓
```

```
SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

```
| id |
| -: |
|  2 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=22591f3fe0883e7c8df6ba25f85446f9)*

Answer (score 1):

Here I am sharing two approaches to select 2nd highest country in terms of quantity purchased.

You can use row_number() ranking window function to do that.

```
with cte as 
(
    SELECT c.country ,row_number()over(order by od.quantity desc) rn
    FROM Customers c 
    JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid=o.customerid 
    JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.orderid=od.orderid 
) select country from cte where rn=2
```

You can also use `offset fetch` instead of limit to achieve your result.

```
SELECT c.country 
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid=o.customerid 
JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.orderid=od.orderid 
order by od.quantity desc 
offset 1 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

offset 1 rows will skip the first row and `fetch next 1 row only` will select only one row after the offset row.